# constexpr function must have one argument value?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, constexpr

According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr), a function declared with `constexpr` must satisfy a few requirements, one of which is as follows:

> there exists at least **one argument value** such that an invocation of the function could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression ...

Well, `constexpr` function can have *no arguments*:

```
constexpr int Bar( /* empty */ ) { return 0xFF; }
constexpr int value = Bar(); // Valid expression
```

`constexpr` function that is invoked as a sub-routine can not determine the whole expression to be core constant expression either.

So what does it mean by *one argument value must exist*?

**[Update for future readers]**

Apparently the description about the requirements of `constexpr function` has been fixed since this question from:

> there exists at least **one argument value** such that an invocation of the function could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression ...

to:

> there exists at least **one set of argument values** such that an invocation of the function could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression ...

Comment: I *think* it means that *for each argument* there exists at least etc.

Comment: @MartinBonner no, it means for all arguments as a whole

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The quote from [en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) is not accurate in regards to the standard, the real quote is (*§7.1.5/5*):

> For a `constexpr` function or `constexpr` constructor that is neither defaulted nor a template, if no argument values exist such that an invocation of the function or constructor could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression (5.20) [...] the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic required.

Which basically says that there must exist one valid set of arguments (the empty set being a valid one in your case).

Comment: So, they screwed up the inverting of the wording.

Comment: If empty set is also considered a valid set, are we even able to have less than `one set of argument values`? (since every function must have at least one set, including an empty set.) I'm just curious if that's just some formality to write the standard.

Comment: @DeanSeo You can have less than one **valid** set of arguments - `constexpr int f(std::string)` is not valid because `std::string` cannot be `constexpr` so whatever the body of `f` might be, there would never be a valid set of arguments making the invocation of `f` a constant expression.

Comment: @Holt Ahh that does make sense. Thanks.

Comment: @DeanSeo (Forgot a bit, sorry) And the empty set is not always valid - `int f() { return sqrt(pi); }` cannot be `constexpr` because the empty set is the only possible set of arguments here and it would not be a valid one because of `sqrt` (unless you have a `constexpr sqrt`) .

Comment: @Holt There must be at least one **valid and possible** set of arguments to produce *constant expression*. Thanks again.

Answer (score 7):

"One argument value" here means "one set of arguments". Nullary functions have one possible argument set, the empty set.

In your case, this single empty argument set does lead to a valid `constexpr` call, so everything is fine.